# Double names in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have this PHP code:

```
<?php
    include 'imagem.php';
    $imagem = new Image(502, 500, '#ffffff');
    $imagem->setFont('Verdana', 14, '#fade45');

    $helpers = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.formice.com/helper/online.json"));
    foreach($helpers as $server=>$list) {
        $line = new Line();
        $line->marginTop = 2;
        $line->addText(strtoupper($server) . ':', 'Verdana Bold', 12, '#009D9D');
        $line->addLineBreak();
        $line->addText(implode(', ', $list), 'Verdana', 12, '#6C77C1', 4);
        $imagem->drawLine($line);
    }
    $imagem->flushImg();

?>
```

And it seems like the names are duplicating because they're added twice in the json file. Can I do something to prevent it via PHP, without modifying the json file?
[image]

Comment: What do you want to prevent again? Not showing `No helpers online`? You need to show your expected output.

Comment: Nope. As you can see, there are two ''Magicalorb'' and ''Bushmeister''. I want to prevent them showing twice

Comment: Use an helper array to add only if not exists. Check with `in_array` and add if not exists: `if(!in_array($name, $names)) { $names[] = $name; /* Your handling,...*/ }`

Comment: @AdrianPreuss Even though this is easily possible, it is much simpler to use `array_unique()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$line->addText(implode(', ', array_unique($list)), 'Verdana', 12, '#6C77C1', 4);
```

The function [array_unique()](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.array-unique.php) gives you the ability to remove any duplicates from your arrays. In this case $list contains the same user twice, the function will then remove them before imploding the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `array_unique`:

```
foreach($helpers as $server=>$list) {
    ...
    $line->addText(implode(', ', array_unique($list)), 'Verdana', 12, '#6C77C1', 4);
    ...
}
$imagem->flushImg();
```

(By the way, why did you post the first part of your code? That really wasn't needed.)

Answer (score 1):

You should use **array_unique** to avoid duplicate elements

```
<?php
    include 'imagem.php';
    $imagem = new Image(502, 500, '#ffffff');
    $imagem->setFont('Verdana', 14, '#fade45');

    $helpers = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.formice.com/helper/online.json"));
    foreach($helpers as $server=>$list) {
        $line = new Line();
        $line->marginTop = 2;
        $line->addText(strtoupper($server) . ':', 'Verdana Bold', 12, '#009D9D');
        $line->addLineBreak();
        $list = array_unique($list);
        $line->addText(implode(', ', $list), 'Verdana', 12, '#6C77C1', 4);
        $imagem->drawLine($line);
    }
    $imagem->flushImg();

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

1.Create an array before the loop starts

```
$my_array = array();
```

2. First line in the loop: check if your line is in the array.

```
if(!in_array($currentline, $my_array)){
    // your printing line code here...
}
```

3. Add the currentline to your array, so it will not be drawn again.

```
$my_array[] = $currentline;
```